# Postgresql array type in prepared statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM public.table1 WHERE arrcol @> ARRAY['someinf'];
```

In order to do this I tried 2 different ways in java.sql.Statement:

```
query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM public.table1 WHERE
arrcol @>?;"); query.setArray(1, conn.createArrayOf("text", new
String[]{id})); // "id" is a string
```

And

```
query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM public.table1 WHERE
arrcol @> ARRAY[?];"); query.setString(1, id); // "id" is a string
```

When I try to dump the raw sql after these lines with toString() I see that the queries are  still same. How can I make this happen with prepared statements?

Comment: That's strange. It works on my computer. JDBC creates nice array literal in the query when I dump it with `query.toString()`.

BTW semicolon is not required in the query string.

Comment: @LisMorski which one works for you?

Comment: Both work. They produce something like:
`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE arrcol @> '{"stack"}'` and
`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE arrcol @> ARRAY['stack']::TEXT[]` (casting to `TEXT[]` is my addition). When executed they also give proper result sets.

Comment: @LisMorski I figured out .toString() doesn't work for me. I use Play! with Postgresql 9.1 and actually .toString is not in API documentation. Anyway, after adding text[] cast it worked strangely, thanks.